# javascript strange object reference behaviour

Tags: javascript

i am getting this strange behaviour from javascript object representation on console and it doesn't make any sense to me

**code1**:

```
var list = {
        todo: {task: "one"}
    }

    console.log(list)

    list.todo.task = "two"
```

[image: chromeconsole]

why would console shows me updated value of task ?
strangely if i just log the task, it shows me different value

**code2:**

```
var list = {
    todo: {task: "one"}
}

console.log(list.todo)

list.todo.task = "two"
```

[image]

Comment: Console logging is asynchronous